# How to to refresh the chart in ChartPanel class after loading the file?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, jfilechooser

I have four classes:
 - ChartService
 - CSVReader
 - FileChooser
 - ChartPanel

My problem is that I don't know how to to refresh the chart in ChartPanel class after loading the file in the FileChooser class. I tried in different ways but the chart doesn't appear.

Please help !!!

ChartService Class :

```
   public void initializeChart() {
        final CombinedDomainXYPlot plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(new DateAxis("Time"));
        this.datasets = new TimeSeriesCollection[SUBPLOT_COUNT];

        for (int i = 0; i < SUBPLOT_COUNT; i++) {
            final TimeSeries series = sensorXseries;

            this.datasets[i] = new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
            final NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis(Y_AXIS_TITLES[i]);
            rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
            final XYPlot subplot = new XYPlot(
                    this.datasets[i], null, rangeAxis, new StandardXYItemRenderer()
            );

            subplot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
            subplot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
            subplot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
            plot.add(subplot);
        }

        final JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Charts", plot);

        chart.setBorderPaint(Color.black);
        chart.setBorderVisible(true);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        final ValueAxis axis =  plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setAutoRange(false);

        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(790, 620));
        chartPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        this.add(chartPanel);
    }
    public TimeSeries createFirstDataSet(ArrayList<DataObject> data) {
        sensorXseries = new TimeSeries("Acceleration X");
        for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            sensorXseries.add(new Millisecond(convertToTimestamp(data.get(i).getStoper())), data.get(i).getAccelerationX());
        }
        return sensorXseries;
    }

    public TimeSeries createSecondDataSet(ArrayList<DataObject> data) {
        TimeSeries sensorYseries = new TimeSeries("Acceleration Y");
        for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            sensorYseries.add(new Millisecond(convertToTimestamp(data.get(i).getStoper())), data.get(i).getAccelerationY());
        }
        return sensorYseries;
    }

    public TimeSeries createThirdDataSet(ArrayList<DataObject> data) {
        TimeSeries sensorZseries = new TimeSeries("Acceleration Z");
        for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            sensorZseries.add(new Millisecond(convertToTimestamp(data.get(i).getStoper())), data.get(i).getAccelerationZ());
        }
        return sensorZseries;
    }

    public void refreshChartPanel() {
        chartPanel.repaint();
    }
```

FileChooser class:

```
public void loadFile() throws Exception {
    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "csv"));

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        fileName= file.getAbsolutePath();
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(fileName);
        chartService = new ChartService();
        chartService.createFirstDataSet(csvReader.getLinesFromFile());
    }

}
```

CSVReader class:

```
public CSVReader(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public ArrayList getLinesFromFile() throws Exception {
        inFile = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(fileName), CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE);
        final String[] header = inFile.getCSVHeader(true);

        CellProcessor [] processors = {null, new ParseDouble(), new ParseDouble(), new ParseDouble(), new ParseInt(), new ParseInt()};

        dataObjectArray = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
        while((dataObject = inFile.read(DataObject.class, header, processors)) != null) {
            dataObjectArray.add(dataObject);
        }
        return dataObjectArray;
    }
```

ChartPanel class:

```
public ChartPanel() {
         initializeChartPanel();
    }

    private void initializeChartPanel() {

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Chart:"));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(824, 0));
        ChartService chartService = new ChartService();
        chartService.initializeChart();

        this.add(chartService);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your chart to a [`org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html), which extends `JPanel` and "registers with the chart to receive notification of changes to any component of the chart." As in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513), data sets typically provide this notification by default when updated. Your `ChartPanel` does not appear to register any listeners at all.

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler: `setVisible()` may be missing; absent an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) we can only guess. `JFreeChart` is not a `JComponent`, so `updateUI()` seems adventitious.