# How to get event on finish drawing bar chart in jFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart, vaadin

I'm using jFreeChart via JFreeChartWrapper in Vaadin and have problems on drawing it. 
Data for charts is getting in runtime and it could take some time. 
So I want to add progress indicator to notify the user about image loading (before it closes the window).

I tried to resolve this problem by adding temporary layout for ProgressIndicator and using it until receiving some event from charts:

```
final AbsoluteLayout loadLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
loadLayout.setImmediate(true);
ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
progress.setVisible(true);
loadLayout.addComponent(progress, "right: 500px; top: 200px;");
setContent(loadLayout);
```

Meanwhile, chart are added in another layout:

```
JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Text", "", "", res, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, false, false); 

barChart.addProgressListener(new ChartProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void chartProgress(ChartProgressEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getType() == ChartProgressEvent.DRAWING_FINISHED) {
            loadLayout.setVisible(false);
            setContent(layout);
            layout.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}); 
JFreeChartWrapper chartWrap = new JFreeChartWrapper(barChart);
layout.addComponent(chartWrap);
```

But what I get - is only progress indicator, I never get ChartProgressEvent. And I don't see where this event if fired in JFreeChart.

Is it possible to fix it or I should better use other Vaadin plugin for charts?

Answer (score 1):

To receive such events, you need to add your chart to a `ChartPanel`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226303/230513).

Comment: Thank you for reply! But I don't use Swing, so if I'll add the chart to a ChartPanel, I still ought to add the chart to a ChartWrapper for displaying in Vaadin. And I still don't receive event.